# View the results in a view or table valued function

Tags: sql

I have a query which compares two requests and displayes yes/no based on comparing each column returned in the select query. How do i change this to be able to retreive the same results in a view or a table valued function. I get the results when i use the SQL to create a Stored procedure but our Business objects application is unable to execute the SQL

Below is my SQL

```
DECLARE @Foo TABLE (requestid int,
receiveddate datetime,
neededby datetime,busneed varchar(1000) ,
rptcomments varchar(1000),
reportfrequency varchar(100),
defineschedule varchar(250),
schedulebasedon varchar(250) ,
clmsrvdtfrom datetime,
clmsrvdtthru datetime ,
clmpddtfrom datetime,
clmpddtthru datetime
)

INSERT @Foo (requestid,receiveddate,neededby,busneed,rptcomments,reportfrequency,defineschedule,schedulebasedon,clmsrvdtfrom,clmsrvdtthru,clmpddtfrom,clmpddtthru)
select requestid,receiveddate,neededby,busneed,rptcomments,reportfrequency,defineschedule,schedulebasedon,clmsrvdtfrom,clmsrvdtthru,clmpddtfrom,clmpddtthru
from report_request where requestid = 1494
INSERT @Foo (requestid,receiveddate,neededby,busneed,rptcomments,reportfrequency,defineschedule,schedulebasedon,clmsrvdtfrom,clmsrvdtthru,clmpddtfrom,clmpddtthru)
select requestid,receiveddate,neededby,busneed,rptcomments,reportfrequency,defineschedule,schedulebasedon,clmsrvdtfrom,clmsrvdtthru,clmpddtfrom,clmpddtthru
from report_request where requestid = 1495


SELECT CAST(requestid AS VARCHAR(MAX)) requestid,
CAST(receiveddate AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS receiveddate,
CAST(neededby AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS neededby,
CAST(busneed AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS busneed,
CAST(rptcomments AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS rptcomments,
CAST(reportfrequency AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS reportfrequency,
CAST(defineschedule AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS defineschedule,
CAST(schedulebasedon AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS schedulebasedon,
CAST(clmsrvdtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtfrom,
CAST(clmsrvdtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtthru,
CAST(clmpddtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtfrom,
CAST(clmpddtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtthru
from Customer_REQUEST where requestid = 1494

UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(requestid AS VARCHAR(MAX)) requestid,
CAST(receiveddate AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS receiveddate,
CAST(neededby AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS neededby,
CAST(busneed AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS busneed,
CAST(rptcomments AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS rptcomments,
CAST(reportfrequency AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS reportfrequency,
CAST(defineschedule AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS defineschedule,
CAST(schedulebasedon AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS schedulebasedon,
CAST(clmsrvdtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtfrom,
CAST(clmsrvdtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtthru,
CAST(clmpddtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtfrom,
CAST(clmpddtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtthru
from CUSTOMER_REQUEST where requestid = 1495

UNION ALL


SELECT 
    CASE WHEN A.requestid = B.requestid THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'  END as requestid,
    CASE WHEN A.receiveddate = B.receiveddate THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as receiveddate,
    CASE WHEN A.neededby = B.neededby THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END neededby,
    CASE WHEN A.busneed = B.busneed THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END busneed,
    CASE WHEN A.rptcomments = B.rptcomments THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END rptcomments,
    CASE WHEN A.reportfrequency = B.reportfrequency THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as reportfrequency,
    CASE WHEN A.defineschedule = B.defineschedule THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as defineschedule,
    CASE WHEN A.schedulebasedon = B.schedulebasedon THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as schedulebasedon,
    CASE WHEN A.clmsrvdtfrom = B.clmsrvdtfrom THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmsrvdtfrom,
    CASE WHEN A.clmsrvdtthru = B.clmsrvdtthru THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmsrvdtthru,
    CASE WHEN A.clmpddtfrom = B.clmpddtfrom THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmpddtfrom,
    CASE WHEN A.clmpddtthru = B.clmpddtthru THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmpddtthru

FROM
    (SELECT * FROM @Foo WHERE requestid = 1494) AS A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM @Foo WHERE requestid = 1495) AS B

ON 1 = 1
```

Need help please

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
CREATE VIEW _test
AS
SELECT CAST(requestid AS VARCHAR(MAX)) requestid,
CAST(receiveddate AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS receiveddate,
CAST(neededby AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS neededby,
CAST(busneed AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS busneed,
CAST(rptcomments AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS rptcomments,
CAST(reportfrequency AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS reportfrequency,
CAST(defineschedule AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS defineschedule,
CAST(schedulebasedon AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS schedulebasedon,
CAST(clmsrvdtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtfrom,
CAST(clmsrvdtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtthru,
CAST(clmpddtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtfrom,
CAST(clmpddtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtthru
from Customer_REQUEST where requestid = 1494

UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(requestid AS VARCHAR(MAX)) requestid,
CAST(receiveddate AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS receiveddate,
CAST(neededby AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS neededby,
CAST(busneed AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS busneed,
CAST(rptcomments AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS rptcomments,
CAST(reportfrequency AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS reportfrequency,
CAST(defineschedule AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS defineschedule,
CAST(schedulebasedon AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS schedulebasedon,
CAST(clmsrvdtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtfrom,
CAST(clmsrvdtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtthru,
CAST(clmpddtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtfrom,
CAST(clmpddtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtthru
from CUSTOMER_REQUEST where requestid = 1495

UNION ALL


SELECT 
    CASE WHEN A.requestid = B.requestid THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'  END as requestid,
    CASE WHEN A.receiveddate = B.receiveddate THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as receiveddate,
    CASE WHEN A.neededby = B.neededby THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END neededby,
    CASE WHEN A.busneed = B.busneed THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END busneed,
    CASE WHEN A.rptcomments = B.rptcomments THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END rptcomments,
    CASE WHEN A.reportfrequency = B.reportfrequency THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as reportfrequency,
    CASE WHEN A.defineschedule = B.defineschedule THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as defineschedule,
    CASE WHEN A.schedulebasedon = B.schedulebasedon THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as schedulebasedon,
    CASE WHEN A.clmsrvdtfrom = B.clmsrvdtfrom THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmsrvdtfrom,
    CASE WHEN A.clmsrvdtthru = B.clmsrvdtthru THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmsrvdtthru,
    CASE WHEN A.clmpddtfrom = B.clmpddtfrom THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmpddtfrom,
    CASE WHEN A.clmpddtthru = B.clmpddtthru THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmpddtthru

FROM
    (select requestid,receiveddate,neededby,busneed,rptcomments,reportfrequency,defineschedule,schedulebasedon,clmsrvdtfrom,clmsrvdtthru,clmpddtfrom,clmpddtthru
from report_request where requestid = 1494) AS A
INNER JOIN
    (select requestid,receiveddate,neededby,busneed,rptcomments,reportfrequency,defineschedule,schedulebasedon,clmsrvdtfrom,clmsrvdtthru,clmpddtfrom,clmpddtthru
from report_request where requestid = 1495) AS B
ON 1 = 1
```